# maximum stack usage from elf file

Tags: c, stack, vxworks, powerpc, wind-river-workbench

Is there any way to get maximum "stack usage" of a vxworks C project code
compiled for PPC architecture using `ccppc` on WindRiver Workbench?

Comment: Stack usage can vary between the runs (think of a recursion with a variable depth). So no, there is no way. You can get it for a particular run.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Tools such as https://www.absint.com/stackanalyzer/index.htm can give you worst-case , and it will tell you if there is a particular reason it cannot determine it (e.g. you use recursion on with a non bounded number of calls).

Answer (score 2):

For various obvious reasons, there is no practical way to get this from static analysis - it is non-trivial to predict the program flow. For a simple program perhaps, but any useful system with network interfaces, configuration files etc etc would be almost impossible to model. Recursion in particular would cause major problems.

Of much more use would be the actual stack usage in a running system, and luckily there is a tool to do just that - the `checkStack` shell command.

This relies on the stack having been intialised with a known pattern (I think 0xEE), and checkStack then looks for the highwater mark of usage - i.e. the first location which doesn't contain that well-known value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a method to statically analyze stack usage without running any code. However, there are probably two ways that I know which might give a good hint:

1) Fill the stack with some known pattern (e.g.`0xAA`). Execute your code for a reasonable amount of time. Then analyze the stack again to see the highest point until which the stack content was altered. This method already has a problem as in, how long is "reasonable amount of time"?

2) Sample the value of Stack Pointer while program execution and then make a statistical guess on the amount of stack usage.

As @Eugene Sh. pointed there is probably no way to actually get the stack usage without running any code.